# How to change a bool in firestore document with scheduled functions?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

How can I change a variable in firestore using scheduled functions once per day? I need to switch a boolean contained in the document field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Cloud functions support Cron jobs with interpretive text.
Looking at their documentation you can see a [base example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) that would interest you. Using this example, I have modified it for your needs and you just need to update the document path and field path. If you need to query to find all booleans, this would be a more resource-intense procedure but would follow the same structure.

```js
// Cloud functions is required to trigger pubsub behavior
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize the admin sdk so we have a client to work with
admin.initializeApp();
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun((context) => {

  // Create reference to document
  const DocumentReference = admin.firestore().doc("path/toDocument");

  // Read document value to get boolean
  DocumentReference.get();
    .then(snapshot =>

    // Store boolean value
    const BooleanValue = snapshot.data().FieldwithBoolean;

    // Update the document reference with the boolean inverted
    DocumentReference.update({FieldWithBoolean: (!BooleanValue) });
    return;
  })
  .catch(err => console.warn(err));
  return null;
})
```

You can specify the time trigger with any of the following, just be aware this is based on the local time from the origin server

- every 24 hours
- every monday 09:00